# fn.yiiListView.update how to not hide the list before ajax send?

Tags: jquery, yii

I'm using `fn.yiiListView.update` too update my CListView. I noticed that every time this function gets triggered, it **clears the clistview first**, then load, then output the new listview.

How can I make it so it does not clear the old listview until the new thing is loaded, so user won't notice a blank listview with loader image only during this process?

Please advice, thanks.

---

not sure this is the correct source or not but i found this online, any ideas?
https://kenai.com/nonav/projects/yiiblog/sources/source/content/public/assets/5dfaf88d/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js?rev=b7ee7f73f7c908ba74c8453d495bc089d27f8225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see nothing happens with the list before sending ajax request excepting [setting loading CSS class](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/zii/widgets/assets/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js#L174) that is `loading` by default.

Probably you have some styles for this class that hide the list.

Another assumption: such behavior is defined by `CListView`'s default CSS file. In this case you can try to disable the file by setting [cssFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#cssFile-detail) property of `CListView` to `false`.